# Where is stored the 'NOT FOR REPLICATION' BIT

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am scripting out the foreign keys for a SQL Server database, and so far I have been able to find all the pertinent information to add a foreign key to the table. 
The only piece of code that is missing is the 'NOT FOR REPLICATION' (see below) 
Does anyone know where does this piece of information live?

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Accountxxxx]  WITH NOCHECK ADD
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Accountxxxx_Accountxxxx_zzzz] 
FOREIGN KEY([D_XX_Guid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[second_table_name] ([Guid])
NOT FOR REPLICATION
```

Thanks,
E.

Answer (score 1):

[`sys.foreign_keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx) contains that information in a fairly straightforward fashion:

```
is_not_for_replication    bit    FOREIGN KEY constraint was created by using the NOT FOR REPLICATION option.
```

If that's not what you're after, perhaps you can elaborate on how you're doing your scripting (SSMS should be scripting this option as appropriate).